# AVAudioPlayer fails with error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)"

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

This is my code sample... for few audio files (mp4 extension) it fails with exception "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)"
I downloaded container from iPhone and confirmed the file exist on path

```
do {  

    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

     //guard let player = player else { return }
     audioPlayer.delegate = self
     audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
     audioPlayer.play()
     audioPlayer.volume = 1.0

     if timer != nil && timer.isValid {
         timer.invalidate()
         timer = nil
     }

     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(LynkAudioPlayer.checkPlayTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

} catch let error as NSError {
     print(error.description)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine. This error occurs because you are either accessing a file that is not at the specified `url` or the value is otherwise `nil` after it returns. Ensure you have a properly formed url for the resource accessed with `AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)`. The audio data must also be in a format supported by Core Audio. You may want to check if `audioPlayer` is `nil` after setting:

```
audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

if audioPlayer != nil { 
    audioPlayer.delegate = self
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
    audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
} else {
    //try to load a different resource?
}
```

Comment: `audioPlayer` throws an exception on your first line even with mp3 audio

Comment: [AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1387281-init) throws, ensure you are wrapping your code in a do/try/catch statement. Here's a helpful resource that appears up to date: http://artoftheapp.com/ios/playing-audio-using-avaudioplayer-swift/  or https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-play-sounds-using-avaudioplayer

Comment: Thanks, fixed. The mistake was in my case `audioPlayer` was a local variable